# No write access to child folder

Tags: windows-xp, directory, windows-server-2003, shared-directory

I created a directory and gave the user (called 'Brad') write permissions.

Brad can create files and directories inside his parent directory.

However, he can't write to the sub-directory.

That is, he accesses the parent directory, creates a new directory within, BUT this new directory created does not give him write permission.

The Admin has to go into the sub directory reassign him permissions.

So the question is: Why aren't the permissions being inherited by the sub-directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-R, you need to give permissions to all preceding sub directories... In linux this is done by writing   -R, no idea for MS

try: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313398
or: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/acl_inherit_permissions.mspx?mfr=true

Update: An example of this (on Linux using Terminal, assuming your currenly located in the parent directory of the specific directory your concerned with)...

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data dlfiles/    ... This will only modify the ownership of the parent directory
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data dlfiles/    ... This will modify all the sub directories too


sudo chmod -R 777 dlfiles/ ... This will modify the Read-Write-Execute permissions to Everyone can RWX.
```